# Interpreters: how do they manage system resources? Differences from virtual machine

Tags: process, operating-system, virtual-machine, interpreter

I was wondering how interpreted languages manage system resources.

Do they have a single process for the interpreter, which asks for resources to the Operating System and decides how to distribute these resources to the script in execution? Or do they create an other process which makes System Calls directly to the Operating System?

I expect that there is only one process exclusively for my program; on the other hand, a process for the interpreter MUST exist and at the beginning of the execution of my program I don't know how big my process should be (I haven't already translated all code to op-code). Therefore it looks like if my program is running using resources given to the interpreter process by the OS, but in this case the interpreter would act just like a virtual machine...

So, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do anything other than calculate, like read or write files, interact with the user, allocate memory, etc., a process must make requests to the operating system.

An interpreter must make requests to the operating system whenever it needs to use more memory, perform input/output, and so on.

Within the process, the interpreter figures out what the interpreted program wants to do, and then sends requests to the operating system asking the operating system to do the things for which the interpreted program is asking.

Comment: So, what is the difference between an interpreter and a Virtual Machine (like JVM)?

Comment: Formal definitions vs. how words are actually used: Nowadays, we tend to use "interpreter" for any system that reads and executes source code at the same time, even if it does some translation/compiling internally. Python is compiled to byte codes and then executed by a virtual machine, but we generally call it an "interpreter" because those steps are combined. With Java they're two separate processes. "javac" compiles the Java into JVM byte codes, and "java" interprets those byte codes.  "java" uses system calls to interact with the outside world (user interface, files, network, etc.).